# How to do a Word Count on Multiple Textareas using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, word-count

I have successfully did a word count on a text area using the following JS:

```
   jQuery('span.after-amount').append(' - You have <span class="wordcount">0</span> words.'); 

   jQuery('textarea').on('input', function($) {

      var regex = /\s+/gi;
      var count =  jQuery(this).val().trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(" ").length;

      $('.wordcount').html(count);


    });
```

My HTML:

```
<textarea class="tmcp-field tmcp-textarea" name="tmcp_textarea_2"></textarea>
<span class="after-amount">You have <span class="wordcount">0</span> words.</span>

<textarea class="tmcp-field tmcp-textarea" name="tmcp_textarea_2"></textarea>
<span class="after-amount">You have <span class="wordcount">0</span> words.</span>

<textarea class="tmcp-field tmcp-textarea" name="tmcp_textarea_2"></textarea>
<span class="after-amount">You have <span class="wordcount">0</span> words.</span>
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/we3qhky2/).

I need to get a word count for each text area, is there an easy way to do this without selecting each textarea individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution, first I change your event handler to `keyup`, and starting count of each textarea value's length using `$(this)` so you get the current textarea.

```
$(function(){
   $('textarea').on('keyup', function(){
      var wordsLength = $(this).val().length;
      $(this).next().find('.wordcount').html(wordsLength);
   });
});
```

Check this [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/we3qhky2/1/). Hope this helps

Comment: Awesome thanks! Works great, just change $(this).val().length to $(this).val().trim().split(' ').length for words instead of characters.

Comment: Ouch, I forgot to add that one. Okay

Answer (score 1):

Just finding `.wordcount` into `<li>`

```
jQuery('textarea').on('input', function($) {
        var regex = /\s+/gi;
        var count =  jQuery(this).val().trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(" ").length;
        jQuery(this).parent().find('.wordcount').html(count);
);
```