# Jquery character count for each of many textareas/textboxes

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, sharepoint, word-count

I'm trying to count the number of characters in each textarea on a page. I've decided to use the code below ([taken from here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403415/how-to-do-a-word-count-on-multiple-textareas-using-jquery), however I am struggling to get it working.

```
 $(function(){
 $('textarea').on('keyup', function(){
  var wordsLength = $(this).val().length;
  $(this).next().find('').html(wordsLength);
  });
 });
```

Below are my html and css. I am not able to edit the CSS or Html directly, only using jquery scripts. I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```css
table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  border-color: grey;
}

input[type=password],
input[type=text],
input[type=file],
input:not([type]),
select,
textarea,
.sp-peoplepicker-topLevel,
.sp-peoplepicker-topLevelDisabled,
.sp-peoplepicker-autoFillContainer,
.ms-inputBox {
  border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.90);
  color: #444444;
}

textarea {
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
  text-rendering: auto;
  color: -internal-light-dark-color(black, white);
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: start;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;
  background-color: -internal-light-dark-color(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(59, 59, 59));
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
  flex-direction: column;
  resize: auto;
  cursor: text;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 0em;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: -internal-light-dark-color(rgb(118, 118, 118), rgb(195, 195, 195));
  border-image: initial;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" role="presentation">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:100%;"><textarea style="display:none;" origvalue="<p>​I can't speak</p><p>This is a great improvement</p><p><br/>&amp;#160;</p>" spellcheck="true" maxlength="225">&lt;p&gt;​I can't speak&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;This is a great improvement&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
        <div class="ms-rtestate-field ms-rtefield ms-inputBox ms-rtestate-write ms-inputBoxActive" style="min-height:84px;width:75%;" disabled="disabled" contenteditable="true" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-haspopup="true" aria-multiline="true" spellcheck="true" rtedirty="false">
          <p>​I can't spek</p>
          <p>This is <span id="ms-rterangecursor-start" rtenodeid="1"></span><span id="ms-rterangecursor-end"></span>a great immmprovemet</p>
          <p><br>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is because you've attached the event handler to the `textarea` yet the visible element that's being typed in to is a contenteditable `div`. As such you need to correct your selector. As this element is a `div` you need to use `text()` or `html()` to read its content, not `val()`. It would also make more sense to use the `input` event for this.

Secondly, you need to fix the selector which targets the element to display the character count in.

```js
$(function() {
  $('div[contenteditable="true"]').on('input', function() {
    var wordsLength = $(this).text().length;
    $(this).siblings('.count').html(wordsLength);
  }).trigger('input');
});
```

```css
table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  border-color: grey;
}

input[type=password],
input[type=text],
input[type=file],
input:not([type]),
select,
textarea,
.sp-peoplepicker-topLevel,
.sp-peoplepicker-topLevelDisabled,
.sp-peoplepicker-autoFillContainer,
.ms-inputBox {
  border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.90);
  color: #444444;
}

textarea {
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
  text-rendering: auto;
  color: -internal-light-dark-color(black, white);
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: start;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;
  background-color: -internal-light-dark-color(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(59, 59, 59));
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
  flex-direction: column;
  resize: auto;
  cursor: text;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 0em;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: -internal-light-dark-color(rgb(118, 118, 118), rgb(195, 195, 195));
  border-image: initial;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" role="presentation">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:100%;"><textarea style="display:none;" origvalue="<p>​I can't speak</p><p>This is a great improvement</p><p><br/>&amp;#160;</p>" spellcheck="true" maxlength="225">&lt;p&gt;​I cannt spek&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;This is a great improvement&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
        <div class="ms-rtestate-field ms-rtefield ms-inputBox ms-rtestate-write ms-inputBoxActive" style="min-height:84px;width:75%;" disabled="disabled" contenteditable="true" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-haspopup="true" aria-multiline="true" spellcheck="true" rtedirty="false">
          <p>​I cannt spek</p>
          <p>This is <span id="ms-rterangecursor-start" rtenodeid="1"></span><span id="ms-rterangecursor-end"></span>a great immmprovemet</p>
          <p><br>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
        <span class="count"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How would I add the  <span class="count"></span> using Jquery?

Comment: `$('<span class="count" />').appendTo('.yourParentElement');`